# Should developers fix bugs in their own code?

Tags: development-process, code-quality, productivity

This is more of a philosophical question.

I have recently started working on a new team and I see here a pressure on developers to fix bugs in their own code. Whenever a bug is found in a feature, the person who coded the feature is assigned that bug.

As a result, I see a lot of [anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) in the code and faulty assumptions that don’t get reworked: instead new code is built onto them. Many developers leave the code in such a state that no one really can understand it afterwards - which to me is the enduring effect of the “fix-your-own-bugs” approach. I guess if later the original coder is the one who fixes a bug, copying code 12 times isn’t really an issue: he/she presumably may remember those 12 places that need changes. But if it is someone new assigned to that code the they will not - resulting in new bugs.

I never before worked in an environment like this. I am used to working on *both my own bugs and other people’s*. I am used to leaving my code in a self-explanatory state and adding comments if it doesn’t seem clear enough. I am used to leaving my code in a state that someone else assigned to it after me can easily work on it.

So what are benefits of the “fix-your-own-bugs” approach other than the benefit of *saving time in the short term* ?

Am I wrong in considering this a bad practice in code production or is it really *how* this policy gets implemented within organizations that is the real problem here ?

Also, I'm not 100% sure what kind of tags I should add for this question. IMHO this issue impacts *productivity* and *code quality* directly, so I think those tags are pertinent. And this issue is definitely associated with *development-process*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is fixing bugs made by other people a good approach?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/is-fixing-bugs-made-by-other-people-a-good-approach)

Comment: What happens when someone is on leave or even quits?

Comment: "person is assigned the bug". Who's doing the assigning? The biggest anti-pattern you mention is individual developer being assigned work by someone else. Why can't the work be the responsibility of the whole team and individuals trusted to pick appropriate tasks for themselves?

Comment: Generally you want developers to fix their own bugs so that they can learn from their mistakes and possibly reduce the number of times they repeat that mistake or take other counter measures.  Otherwise people have a tendency to get reckless because they don't have to clean up their own messes.

Comment: You are really not asking "should programmers fix their own bugs" but rather "should only one programmer work on a particular program or chunk of code".   I will say that one of the best, most professional development environments I was in had good, experienced programmers that each were responsible for a particular area of the system.

Comment: @DaveG: *"each were responsible for a particular area of the system"* - does that mean "exclusively, without letting anyone else look into their code"? Without any code reviews?

Comment: @DocBrown I think the ones doing code reviews do universal code reviews, not a person assigned to code review a specific feature. What I think DaveG is saying is that each developer was assigned to properly program one specific feature of the project, instead of having multiple people work on the same part. Don't think code reviews has anything to do with this.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan-onstrike: I would be more interested in what DaveG actually meant, not someone else thinks what they meant.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes sir, I just commented on my understanding of it, and if my understanding is right, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @DaveG the issue is - not all developers are equally experienced and skilled. And in your description of the workplace there seem to be no place for training juniors. I will just add that I was a maintainer of projects that I had nothing to do with while they were created. I feel like if it worked like you described, there woud be a vacuum in knowledge and expertise after those developers left. And let's face it - for the most of us, software we create outlive us in companies we work for. Thanks for your comment tho; I will go on a ponder what it is to be developer and teammate :-)

Comment: @DocBrown No, of course not.  One of my coworkers had the expression "let me borrow your eyes" when she wanted me to work with her figuring out a problem.  It's just acknowledging the fact that there is going to be a person most familiar with each area of the codebase, and it makes sense for that person to at least be involved any time that code is altered, even if someone else was making the changes.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan-onstrike Yep, you are correct.  We each had individual areas of expertise, although the entire codebase was of course available for review.

Comment: @emperor-shallots I am always bemused by the talk of "juniors" and "seniors".  We had more experienced and less experienced devs, but basically people were assigned work based on the competence and experience, and were free to consult with whoever they thought could aid them in their tasks.  It sounds like a lot of other companies have a much more rigid hierarchy.

Comment: @DaveG if I am honest your last comment is not understandable to me. Maybe I wasn’t clear, but to me junior is a shortcut to say “person starting their career”. I wasn’t talking about seniors or even job titles. Don’t you think people at the beginning of their career need more mentoring and guidance or do you just not offer them any help? If you think that this is a rigid hierarchy, then explain to me how assigning tasks based on experience and skill is less rigid?

Comment: "you presumably will remember those 12 places that need changes" Absolutely not. Not unless you just wrote it last week. Maybe not even then.

Comment: Why is it assumed that the original author of the code will do a worse job of fixing bugs than someone else?  Or for that matter that the original author of code will copy / paste the same wrong code 12 times?  If I have to fix a bug and realize that same bug is in a couple of places (because I know the code) I'd see that as a chance to refactor and remove duplication.

Comment: Yes, developers should fix bugs in their own code, because (presumably!) they are most familiar with it and are most able to fix the problem.  If they can't fix it, then they should ask for help from a senior developer.

Comment: @John Gordon  *If they can't fix it, then they should ask for help from a senior developer.*  This is the nub of the matter. Junior devs stuck on a bug fix **should be able to refer to a senior dev for help.** But many software development teams have a culture that, while theoretically allowing this, silently discourages it by (1) having no formal/informal procedure for it; (2) challenging everyone asking for help to show that they have done everything humanly possible themselves first; (3) making impatient faces and gestures when they do agree to help; (4) patronizing those seeing help.

Comment: Only reason why this hasn't already been closed as "opinion-based" is that developers love to partake in these endless discussions where everyone's assumptions and contexts clash in a joyful dialogue of the deaf :D

Comment: So: what context? A distributed open source community of hundreds? A team of NASA engineers? 2 people maintaining a legacy banking system? A front-end design studio? A team of video game devs in a crunch?...

Answer (score 94):

This seems more a failure of your code review process than who is fixing the bugs. If the

> anti-patterns in the code and faulty assumptions that don’t get reworked

aren't getting called out and corrected before the change is merged **independent of whether this is a bug fix or the initial implementation**, you have bigger problems than whether developers are fixing their own bugs or not.

Comment: I do agree there is an issue with code review; which I guess is something I am also working on changing consistently despite the constant pushback I am getting; however, I think that devs in this situation feel like they specialise and aren’t as concerned with modules they didn’t work on - and I think if they had to, that would make them more inclined to take responsibility for the whole codebase instead of that one part they consider theirs. I guess I am curious where does that idea of isolated responsibility comes from and whether this approach is also something that should be changed.

Comment: Sure. But again, that's a bigger issue of team ownership vs individual ownership - worry about that, not about the smaller issue of how bugs are assigned.

Comment: Code review is a costly, error-prone, manual way to catch bugs though.

Comment: @Telastyn  Do the math on costs.  One bug costs probably 10-100 or more times what a single code review costs.  So if a code review catches just one bug, it pays for itself at least 10 times over.  Even the smallest bug that makes it to integration testing has costs measured in the tens of person-hours.  If a bug reaches the customer, it's hundreds of hours.  IME it's bad devs who don't want their code reviewed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - sure, let’s assume that every code review that finds a bug pays for itself 10 times over. That means you need to find at least one bug in every ten PRs to make it a win. You have some pretty poor unit tests (or too large PRs) to come in with a ratio that bad. And in my experience (automated, build triggered) integration test found bugs take far less than tens of person-hours to fix.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: this argument is flawed, since for finding bugs, tests are often more effective than code reviews. The real value of code reviews (with refactorings) is a different one: it helps to keep code understandable and simple, which makes it easier to apply further code changes for new or changed features in less time and without introducing too many new bugs in the first place.

Comment: @Telastyn I think security vulnerabilities are a kind of "bug" which is usually not caught by automated testing, but can be found and fixed by good code reviews.

Comment: I think this discussion is getting off-topic :)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think the discussion is on-topic, since Telastyn seems to say code-reviews are a bad solution to fix bad code, while your answer seems to suggest code-reviews as the solution. I think it is important to argue why manual code-reviews are a better fix for bad code than automated tests.

Comment: @Telastyn *You have some pretty poor unit tests...*  Unit tests are **always** poor - they are written from the same assumptions and interpretation of requirements that the code they're testing is written from.  Wrong assumptions or interpretations mean both wrong code and wrong tests.  Unit tests themselves need review.

Comment: @DocBrown It's not flawed, it's incomplete because it's just a comment.  IMO my point about cost is also the easiest to quantitatively demonstrate the cost benefit of code reviews and immediately and directly rebut the anti-code review sentiment of the previous comment.  Your point it true too.  But unit tests are not complete - see my comment above.  And then there's the fact that developers who know others are going to review their code will do a better job.  The earlier bugs are identified and fixed, the cheaper they are to address, with much less impact to boot.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: sorry, but I think your idea of demonstrating the value of code reviews quantitatively by comparing it to the effort of fixing bugs is definitely flawed since you are arguing with numbers out of thin air - and if you just pick the numbers you like, you can prove anything. Don't get me wrong, I think reviews are really important, but the argument *"because reviews are a low cost approach to find bugs directly"* is attackable.

Comment: @DocBrown Sure, it's attackable.  But only by force-pulling smaller bug-impact numbers out of thin air.  Nevermind the numbers I posted aren't out of thin air - they're from 30+ years of doing this.  If you account for every minute spent dealing with a bug from the moment it's discovered in integration testing, you'll find that even for trivial bugs in the leanest orgs it'll be hard to get that impact under 10 or so hours.  If a bug reaches a customer, that number explodes by at least an order of magnitude - in addition to the intangible costs to reputation and customer relationships.

Comment: @Falco It's not either-or.  Both tests and reviews are IME critical in identifying and correcting bugs as early as possible.

Comment: There is the question at what point you call it a “bug”. My software progresses from non-existing to not compiling to not working to untested to reviewed to passing automated tests to “no problems that I know of”. And _that_ is what gets tested and sometimes has bugs. Before that I don’t count it as bugs.

Answer (score 40):

For recent bugs, I agree with the other answers. Most of those are sorted out in the pull request process and it's a matter of pride and familiarity to fix your own bugs.

However, there are scaling issues with longer-term bugs. The most experienced developers have touched the most code simply by virtue of being there the longest, so you need to transfer ownership to spread the work out. Likewise when someone leaves or joins the company.

Additionally, it often requires more skill to fix a bug than to create one, especially when you get into tricky areas like concurrency. Senior developers tend to get the trickiest bugs escalated to them, and in order to have time to tackle them, need to delegate some of the easier bugs.

If you maintain strict long-term ownership, senior developers end up overwhelmed by volume and junior developers end up overwhelmed by difficulty.

Comment: This is an important point.  The context of 'fix your own bugs' in my mind is mostly within the scope of dev/testing.  Once the code has been approved for production, the dev is somewhat off-the-hook with maybe some sort of 'probation' period caveats.

Comment: "it often requires more skill to fix a bug than to create one" -  so it's probably no good idea to add my extreme bug-creating skills to my resume ...

Comment: I personally enjoy fixing bugs and I hear I am not a very common animal in our developent tribe (seeing that many job postings state working on new features as a perk); but you touched on the issue that I have been tackling in the past and I am wary of in the future - expertise vacuum when someone leaves. But I have a question - what do you consider recent enough to delegate to dev that created the feature? Where would you estimate the cut off for it? Also, thank you for getting sucked into my deliberations :-)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you can always say what I do - "I do bugs" and leave the ambiguity to a listener - they can decide if I mean introducing them to codebase or fixing them.

Comment: I'd add that with regards to requiring more skill to fix a bug - it often also requires some form of a second set of eyes - similar to how writers may not notice an error they made in a book, but their editor will, simply by nature of being a fresh set of eyes and not being able to skim the text -, which solo developers often have to resort to [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to catch their own mistake. They *can* do that, but often things go more smoothly if someone else takes a look at it.

Answer (score 21):

First, to make this formally an answer, here are some possible reasons why the developer should fix their own code:

- They wrote it, they understand it best, they need the least time to fix it.
- They made a mistake, they should be punished for it. *To make it explicit after some comments: this is written somewhat tongue-in-cheek, and I wouldn't agree with such a rule, but there are managers in the wild who might assign tasks according to such reasoning.*

---

However, there are some negative aspects which should also be considered:

- The bug may be caused by a fundamental misunderstanding, and the "fix" only patches the symptoms.
- The original author may be unavailable (vacation, sickness, urgent work in another project, job change). Ever heard of "bus factor"? If only one person knows and understands the code, your bus factor is 1, which is something to avoid.

---

There's a quite different approach which should at least be considered, even if your organization isn't willing to adopt it dogmatically: **Collective Code Ownership**.

In an extreme interpretation, it demands that every developer should be able to pick up and work on code written by another, including when bugs need to be fixed. The extreme isn't always achievable, and that is often used as a straw man argument that collective code ownership can't work. There also is the hidden implication that developers are easily replaceable, which in reality they aren't.

However, if you consider a moderate version of collective code ownership, there may be some advantages:

- Agree on a number of coding conventions, from formatting to use or avoidance of certain language idioms. This makes code often better readable to other team members, including new developers.
- Do code reviews not only to find mistakes, but to understand what a piece of code does and gain shared knowledge.
- When bugs are analyzed and fixed, pair programming (preferably including the original developer) can be helpful even if you don't do it for regular development, as two pairs of eyes often see more, and communication about the cause of a bug helps both people involved to get a better understanding.

Comment: "They make a mistake, they should be punished for it."  -- Really?

Comment: Not my argument. But managers come up with weird reasons why the way they think work should be done is best.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- Joel Spolsky: "On the Excel team we had a rule that whoever broke the build, as their 'punishment', was responsible for babysitting the builds until someone else broke it. This was a good incentive not to break the build..." https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/

Comment: @RobertHarvey In my experience, getting support calls at 3AM is a really strong incentive to produce high-quality solutions and learn from your mistakes.

Comment: I think no one is argueing with the rule "whoever breaks it, fixes it", but I think the term punishment takes it a bit too far. @Hans-MartinMosner I've read for too much weird shit in workplace.stackexchange to know to never take a manager's reasoning as canon.

Comment: "your bus factor is 1" - no, "they understand it **best**". In software development your main resource is time, saving ~50% of the implementation time (AKA cost) by not having to start from scratch is a really strong incentive for having the same person touch the same code.

Comment: I don't know where you work, but where I work, most managers would not say *"They made a mistake, they should be punished for it."*. Instead, they would say *"They made a mistake, they should be given a chance to correct it by themselves and learn from it"*.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: There's a very good reason Joel put the word "punishment" in air quotes.  It's not punitive.  Where I work, we call that "incentive," which is exactly how Joel describes it in the next sentence of the verse you quoted.

Comment: For the "Collective Code Ownership" part, I would add: comment your code in the first part. It can even be useful to yourself when fixing/improving parts later,.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: note Joel was not talking about arbitrary bugs. He was talking about changes which broke a build - something which could surely be prevented in Joel's working environment by working with a little bit more care (for example, by making sure all new files were checked in into source control etc.) Moreover, when it comes to bugfixing, it is debatable what is the higher punishment - when you get a chance to fix your error by yourself, or if this is taken out of your hands to someone else.

Comment: @user3819867 "your bus factor is 1" and "they understand it best" are both true, and both significant contributors to development speed. The latter argument (the one you promote) is quite intuitive but the former is easily forgotten – until it catches you, and the rest of the dev team needs to adopt code that they don't know, and velocity plummets. In the long run you can surely see how that situation can end up _costing_ speed instead of gaining it. So the path, as usual, is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Agree with your first reason, but not the second. The term "punishment" is quite inappropriate. It's important to have a blame-free culture. Bugs should be seen as a consequence of inadequacies in the process used by the team, not as something to be blamed on individuals.

Answer (score 9):

You wrote

> I see a lot of anti-patterns in the code and faulty assumptions that don’t get reworked

but I challenge your idea of that being caused by "developers fixing their own bugs".

When anti-patterns and faulty assumptions don't get reworked in your team now, the situation won't improve just by making devs fixing more of other developers bugs. Quite the opposite, when I have to work on code not written by myself, I suspect myself to lack some understanding of the surroundings, which the original author might have had. This can make me make even more hesitant to change more than the bare minimum necessary to close the bug ticket.

More generally, bug fixing is IMHO the wrong point in time to refactor (at least it should avoided to do both within the same commit). Removing anti-patterns and fixing "wrong assumptions" beyond the ones which were causing the bug should ideally be done at a separate point in time/commit. Better points in time are:

- immediately after one added a feature, when code was extended and became less clear by this extension
- before adding a feature, to make this task easier
- before or after fixing a bug (but not at the same commit, and regardless of who was the author of that code section!) - especially when  the bug fix isn't just fixing an obvious typo
- during code reviews (as Philip Kendall [already wrote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/446621))

So in short, who fixes whose bugs and code quality are usually unrelated issues.

Still, in your situation, I think the bug fixing process can become a starting point for improving the code quality and introducing more code reviews: try to convince the team **to have each bug fix reviewed by a second pair of eyes**. Bugs often come in clusters, and code sections affected by a bug are often worth a second look. Hence the focus for such a review should be on identifying related bugs and letting the reviewer make suggestions for code improvements which prevent to happen this kind of bug again. The original author of that code section - if available - can either be the one who fixes the bug or the one who reviews the fix.

That way, you can satisfy your team's idea of keeping the author of a certain code section informed as well as your idea of getting the code quality improved.

Comment: This. A bug fix should be reviewed by a peer. Without a **validation** process of some sort, what's the guarantee that the developer has made any serious effort to address the issue and didn’t come up with a quick and dirty fix instead? Trust, but verify.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Philip's answer I would like to add that it can be quite demotivating when you do **not** get to fix your own bugs. Maybe not when it's a really small thing like inadvertently writing == instead of != but certainly when the next person decides to go about it in a totally different manner.

Cooperating in the same code base requires respecting each other's work. If something is wrong or missing I would prefer a new issue being assigned to the same person allowing them to dot their i's and cross their t's. This respects their work and has them learn something so they will do better next time.

Comment: Why is it disheartening? Don’t you participate in code review together? If I make a mistake and someone else’s fixes it, I can still talk to them about their approach and review their code; I often communicate in two words things like that to my coworkers as well. No offence, but it all sounds like a big case of hurt feelings, while your code could have benefited from someone else taking a run at it.

Comment: @emperor: Why can't you have both?  I personally like fixing my own bugs (as I have a sense of responsibility about the code I write), but why can't my bug fixes be informed by the code review process?

Comment: @emperor-shallots This is not about code review, I subscribe to the statement that any mistakes/problems regarding code **should** be caught by code review, in which case it would by procedure be sent back to the author of the code in question. This is about the case in which these issues with the code were missed by code review or code review never took place. I claim the same route should be taken as if it were a code review (which it really is, albeit too late). You don't fix issues on behalf of the author while performing code reviews, do you? No, you comment and reject.

Comment: “A really small thing like writing == instead of !=“ - I am still angry about a supposedly senior developer changing “if (ptr != NULL)” to “if (!ptr)” because he was so smart. Creating a bug that was exceedingly rare, totally fatal for customers and impossible to reproduce. And he was too senior to do code reviews.

Comment: @gnasher729 I understand that but it is very different from what I wanted to illustrate. I was talking about an obvious mistake with an equally obvious fix that is addressed without messing with the creative work of the author.

Comment: @gnasher729: you are talking about introducing a bug, not fixing it.

Comment: @MartinMaat but I think that's exactly the point. Someone else might think this is an easy fix for a small mistake - but the original developer maybe had a good reason for writing the code the way it is, because there is a subtle corner case which needs to be addressed. So the original developer should be involved in the fixing, especially for seemingly easy fixes.

Comment: @Falco in that case the original developper is also faulty, subtle corner cases should always be preceded by a comment with a big all caps "WARNING" and an explanation IMO

Comment: @Kaddath most likely yes. But maybe for the developer this "corner case" was so obvious that he didn't think a comment was needed? And the junior dev fixing the "simple bug" simply overlooked it? Both problems can be fixed by a short talk/pairing session to fix the simple bug together (or at least let the original author review the fix)

Answer (score 4):

The question is stated as a yes/no question, but the real answer is "it depends". Sure, if there is a bug in code which I wrote last week and which got deployed this morning, I am probably the most suitable person to fix it, as the code is new enough that I'm the only person familiar with it.

But a bug in code written five years ago, and which only surfaces now because it now gets called in a way which triggers the bug? The original developer may not have looked at the code for years. Heck, the original developer may not be employed anymore. What are you then going to do with a policy of "developers fix their own code"?

What are you going to do with bugs which is caused by the interaction of five different systems, each with their own developers? It may take a long time to pinpoint the bug -- might as well fix that bug when you find it instead of tracking down the original developer and tell her what to fix.

If there is one thing I learned in 40+ years of coding, it is that there are no absolutes. There's no "one size fits all". "Developers fix their own bugs" isn't a policy that's always going to work. Neither is "Bugs get fixed by others".

Comment: Paragraph 2 is going off track near the end - the poster here is not implying they should tie their dev practice to the actual employment of the dev and otherwise render the code unmaintainable. Paragraph 3 is an argument pro unit _and_ integration testing, and is mostly unrelated to the question at hand. I do agree with the overall spirit of this answer as captured by paragraphs 1 and 4.

Comment: @Flater You know, bugs do appear in codebases which employ unit and integration tests. The guideline "develop automated tests to the point that bugs are categorically impossible" isn't practical for most dev teams.

Comment: @neonblitzer: I never said anything to the contrary. I don't think you can get a test suite spot on from the get to. I do believe that by extending the test suite to account for forgotten test cases _if and when_ a bug slips through, you can over time grow your test suite (and your developer experience) to be very resilient and better at not letting bugs slip through.

Comment: @Flater So we agree that automated testing doesn't prevent the situation outlined in paragraph 3. Thus, the paragraph _is_ related to the question at hand – who owns a bug that happens at the intersection of five different systems?

Comment: @neonblitzer The world is decidedly less binary than your last comment is making it out to be. Automated tests will _generally_ catch these issues, and they are a more efficient approach instead of only having a bug assignment policy. Integration collision is very much worthy of testing and (ideally) catching pre merging of the feature that breaks the integration. Of course there are going to be outliers, but the existence of an exception does not disprove the guideline in its entirety. Given paragraph 4, which I already said I agree with, I'm surprised that you've glossed over the nuance here

Comment: @Flater I just thought your dismissal of paragraph 3 as "unrelated" is unwarranted. _Of course_ automated testing reduces bugs. I'm 120 % sure neither the OP nor Abigail need to be reminded of that fact. But that's not what the question is about. Besides, that particular paragraph raises a good practical point – that sometimes there is no owner for the bug even if every line of code has an owner, and you'll have to find some less absolute guideline for bugfix assignment anyway. Which you seem to agree with, so I find your original criticism that much more out of place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, developers should fix bugs in their "own" code. But developers
should also fix bugs in "others" code. I'm using quotes here to
emphasize that most developers doesn't own the code they work on - the
company does - and feelings of ownership are illusory and may be
harmful.

Because in my opinion the core problem here is in the word
"own". Having developers feel that they "own" code have advantages and
disadvantages. The advantages are that it is clear who is responsible
for maintaining some piece of code. That person may also have some
freedom in how they want to structure the code as long as it works and
as long as it adheres to established style guides. Whoever is
responsible becomes a specialist and is is clear who should be able to
answer other developers questions about the code.

But there are disadvantages too. Developers may shy away from fixing
bugs in "others" code for fear of stepping on someone's toes. Perhaps
they'll write a bug report instead, but this introduces bureaucracy if
the fix is relatively simple. It can also reduce code quality if the
developer who "owns" a module is weak and unable to maintain it
properly. A stronger developer may notice that the bug fixes are just
band-aids, but be unwilling to do anything about it since it's not
"their" module. Ownership can also cause problems for the company if
the only developer with deep knowledge of a module quits.

In my opinion, the disadvantages far outweighs the advantages. The
whole development department/team/group should "own" and be
collectively responsible for the codebase -- not individuals. It's
better if everyone has broad, but shallow, knowledge of the codebase
and thus are able to collaborate than if everyone is a specialist, but
with no understanding of what others are doing.

Of course, collective responsibility is hard to achieve in practice
and developers (in my experience) naturally takes on "ownership" of
the code they produce. However, in my opinion, development processes
should de-emphasize this tendency which means that developers should
be encouraged to fix bugs in code written by colleagues.

Comment: Can't coders "express their ownership" of code managed by another coder via the code reviews process ? Then they may make suggestions for improvement **to be implemented by the person responsible for managing that code**. This way their obligation to the overall system is discharged without their recoding another team member's code.

Answer (score 2):

There is more nuance to this question (and answer) than the question title suggests.

### Rogue devs

Your core complaint is that when there's not enough eyes on the code, one dev is able to go rogue without anyone being the wiser. I agree that this is a problematic situation and there should be general team consensus on the work that is being delivered, to ensure that one person does not write things "their" way.

However, having people fix other people's code from the get go is an inefficient way of doing so. A code review is a much better approach here.

You're putting too much on the second person there. Yes, by forcing them to fix the bug you innately force them to understand the code, and with a code review someone could *claim* to have reviewed the code and not actually have done so, but that's no longer a discussion on what developers *should* do, that's an issue with your employee's work ethic.

### Ownership

Let me put it differently. If others always fix someone's problems for them, then how are they ever supposed to learn that what they've been doing is incorrect? And even if they figure that out, what incentivizes them to not do so in the future, since they're not the ones having to clean it all up?

True ownership means you remain responsible for the decisions of your actions. You did it badly, you therefore have to now redo it. Obviously, this is assuming that the person is capable of the required fix - don't send a junior up sh*t creek without a paddle to implement senior level code.

### Team ownership

That being said, team ownership also factors into this. If the original dev is otherwise indisposed and not easily available (whether absent from work or having other commitments that cannot wait), it's perfectly reasonable for someone to help get this feature across the line.

Similarly, there is a (not pedantically defined) statute of limitations on a single person's ownership over the work. If the buggy code has been part of the system for some amount of time, *anyone* can now look at it.
Developers should not carry code in perpetuity. They should carry it during the development stage and it gets inherited by the broader team at some point (this is contextual when it is appropriate to do so).

### Conclusion

- You're pointing at a valid problem but are using the wrong solution to try and fix it.
- In order to get more eyes on the code and prevent rogue devs, institute a code review process.
- If devs are rubberstamping the code reviews without proper reviewing, this either means that they're not trained on how to review code, or they have a problematic work ethic. In either case, it is not the review itself that is causing the issue.
- Devs should exercise ownership over their work, and when they make mistakes, cleaning up their own mistakes is a great learning tool that should not be ignored.
- Where reasonable, the team still owns the work and members should be willing to take on any of the team's tasks. If the bug has existed for some time, the dev is indisposed, or it requires an expertise that the dev does not have, *of course* it is sensible to involve another dev at that point.

Comment: Don't you think though that if responsibity for areas of code is so clearly isolated then code reviewer may be missing bigger context to conduct the review properly? Not by their lack of work ethic, but merely not knowing what they might be missing. I always say that the issue isn't someone's gap in knowledge, but their ignorance that the gap may exist. By not familiarizing themselves with the whole of the project and not feeling responsible for it, other team members may not know what gaps they have. Anyway, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: @emperor-shallots Reviewers without context can confirm that the change is well documented. Maybe because it's self-explanatory, maybe because additional documentation was provided. If the intention is not clear and no further information on it exists, the reviewer can correctly flag that this is lacking and in need of a fix.

Comment: Perhaps a good policy is that one of the code's reviewers should fix the bug?  That's a great opportunity to improve team ownership and understanding.  Obviously, ask the original author for input when it's unclear (and use that information to improve the documentation - e.g. variable names or comments).  This technique has worked well for me recently (both as author and as reviewer).

Comment: @Toby Noting that (1) real learning is only achieved by successful *practice* as opposed to passively receiving info on what is wrong and how to fix it and (2) the Pareto distribution of bugs amongst developers, surely your alternative policy can only lead to (A) most bugs being fixed by the more bug-free developers who eventually review and spot it; and (B) a much slower learning rate by the developers generating the most bugs ? How would you feel if you were a low bug dev but still paid the same as the high bug devs whose code fixes shakle your own productivity and salary ?

Comment: @Trunk You've explained it better than I could, 100% agree with your points.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good points made in the other answers, determining the relative productivity of developers is more difficult when they are not fixing their own bugs.  I'm not saying it can't be done, but that it requires more rigorous tracking and analysis.

If you have every developer fixing their own bugs, the amount of (roughly equivalently sized) features that a sloppy developer can produce will be less than one who is writing code at a more optimal level of care and/or using better techniques.

That is, if a developer is trying to close out as many items as possible and bugs are distributed to the team as a whole, they can artificially increase their throughput by churning out defective code or in technical terms: 'crap'.  There's an opposite issue where developers can be too worried about creating defects and become too careful.  That's why it's important to focus on the throughput of working features to production and not the amount of (non-production) defects.

If you push the defects back to the developers, it creates a natural feedback loop and they can learn to optimize their productivity with limited additional information.  If you don't do that, it means you need to track the defects and who created them over time and then communicate that back to the developers who are creating excessive defects.  This is problematic for a few reasons but the biggest is that it may cause the developers to try to minimize defects to avoid being 'blamed' for them instead of optimizing for throughput.  If this tracking isn't done, the management (lead etc.) can easily mistake their least productive developers as the most and vice-versa.  The best developers will tend to become disgruntled by this situation and may quit.

The side benefit is that it's also much easier to see which developers are truly the most productive and reward/promote them accordingly.  The thought of trying to track and attribute defects and then find the optimal rate seems pretty daunting and I'll assert that it probably requires some guess-work.  It's also unlikely that most developers will know use that feedback to achieve the real goal (i.e.: working production features) directly.

If you have a situation where one developer is so bogged down by their bugs that they can't get out from under them, you may need to distribute those defects to other team members.  However, this would be a clear indication that you have a developer who needs support and/or mentoring and (unfortunately) may not be able to perform their job adequately.  Obviously, if you let someone go or they quit, the rest of the team will need to fix whatever defects they left unresolved.

**NOTE**: I need to make it clear that I am talking only about bugs found in during development and testing.  Production defects are a failure of the team/process and attributing them to a single person is highly misguided and (somewhat paradoxically) tends to lead to more production defects. The question of how a defect got into production without detection is much more important than how it was created.

P.S. I think this is being misinterpreted.  This is not about punishment. It's about feedback loops and letting developers 'manage themselves'. As an analogy, there's a condition that certain people have where they feel no pain. While initially, this might seem like a good thing, it's actually a really big problem. No one wants to suffer through the pain of being burned but these people can suffer from serious injuries where they (e.g.) place their hand on something very hot and have no idea they are getting 3rd-degree burns until they smell it or see smoke. Having your defects come back to you is like that immediate pain feedback most people have.  You learn of the error you made much closer to when you made it.  This allows you to correct and learn much more efficiently.

Comment: I find a focus on "individual productivity" to be harmful in a development team.  It's much more useful to demonstrate what the _team_ can achieve.  Team members obviously have a perception of their peers' strengths and weaknesses, and what support and coaching each needs, but in my experience that's best kept internal to the team. Attempting to measure individuals promotes damaging competitive behaviours, notably an unwillingness to spend time helping others.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's basically my point.  By not providing a direct feedback loop to the developer, it means that someone has to focus on this.  I've been on and managed teams with developers who have negative productivity.  That is, their main output is unnecessary work for other team members.  I that isn't addressed, it will create bigger problems.  It's much better for everyone to work with the developer directly and not get everyone else involved with their challenges.

Comment: @Toby All well and good but the team member coached/mentored by a co-worker has to offer *post hoc* justification for the help offered. And surely the very least he/she can do is to implement in their own code the bug fixes or code improvements suggested in reviews. Anything less seems to me to be inadequate for team membership.

Comment: @Toby Speight  Your profile shows you to be a highly experienced and proficient software professional. So I don't think you are giving a contrarian opinion for the hell of it. Would you please elaborate on how your process of bug fix allocation to other coders operates and how it raises the capabilities of the buggy coders despite the absence of coding fixes to their own bugs ? I want to understand your viewpoint clearly.

Comment: @Trunk, in my team we don't _allocate_ work like that to individuals, except for straightforward tasks that are already well-understood by the whole team.  So when the bug is a simple omission, then the developer who introduced it is likely to say, "that's a simple fix - I'll add the relevant tests and code"; when it's more complex, I'd expect a couple of developers to look into it together and come up with a shared understanding of what needs to be done.  We don't like to silo knowledge within individuals - that's why attempting to measure _individual_ output are in conflict with our values.

Comment: We consider _team_ productivity to be measurable; sprint retrospectives often look at how we can improve our communication, knowledge sharing and individual skill-sets to give higher velocity.  We'll certainly do our best within the team to support engineers' personal development, and that often involves some coaching or pair development in their weaker areas (we all have some!).  But no need to air our dirty laundry publicly - outsiders are only interested in the results they can expect from the team, and so we optimise for team productivity rather than that of individuals.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. Your process is enlightened and sensible to varying individual needs while refining a company-wide approach to software development. It seems to be alert to individualism getting out of hand in a loose group situation. Almost Japanese in a way.

Comment: @TobySpeight Distributing defects to other team members directly exposes the failures of developers to other developers.  This can be useful: sometimes we can learn from the mistakes of others.  If your team is roughly even in skill level, it will tend to work OK but I've seen it go very poorly when the skill levels of the members vary.

Comment: I think we're in agreement - we can learn from each other within a team; we don't need to expose that more widely (except when we think we have a useful lesson we can share with other teams - at my work, we avoid naming individuals when we do that).

Comment: @TobySpeight OK.  I just want to be clear that what I am proposing is not about retribution.  I've definitely experienced situations where Bob spends half their day fixing John's defects.  Then he's complaining about it in the break room and Bill notes that he too is spending half his day dealing with John's issues.  Then their manager starts hearing that John needs to be fired from other team members.  Sometimes people need to be let go for performance problems (as a last resort) but that isn't a good way for it to happen.

Comment: Software development companies (or software divisions of commercial businesses) usually don't have a system for formally consolidating solutions or recommendations for commonly encountered coding issues - a sort of Our Coding Manual, maintained by the company's acting codemaster. Having distilled wisdom from past experience well-indexed might go a long way towards helping junior devs become more independent.

Answer (score 0):

A bug is a deviation from wished, expected, or specified behavior or state.  Bug fixing is implementing a new (wished/expected/specified) behavior or state.  The only thing that the word “bug” adds is a negative attitude to the old behavior; however, technically, bug fixing is simply the process of implementing a requirement (for software at least, as actually removing insects from hardware is manual labor).
So your question is simply whether the same developers should continue working on implementing a requirement concerning a piece of code they worked on before. Here are my answers:

- For a good developer and good code: yes.
- For a good developer and bad code: the developer has probably improved in the meantime, but still, determine first why the code was bad before taking any decision.
- For a bad developer and good code: something went wrong in the meantime with the developer, so give the code to a good developer.
- For a bad developer and bad code: give the requirements to a good developer and ask him/her to write the program anew.

(Naturally, it's sometimes hard to determine the quality of the developer and the code. In such cases without full information, it's hard to give a good piece of advice.)

Comment: I disagree with the answer because a "bug" is not defined as "what it used to do" (i.e. the old behavior), but rather "not doing what we had already asked it to do". In ITIL terms, a bug is an incident, not a change. If the old behavior was once correct, and now they want new behavior, that's a change and not an incident (and therefore not a bug either).

Comment: _"So your question is simply whether the same developers should continue working on implementing a requirement concerning a piece of code they worked on before."_ I also disagree with this, to the point of expecting the actual opposite. A new change should be able to be handled by any dev. A bug should in principle be able to be handled by any dev but is better assigned to the dev who made the mistake as a point of learning - assuming said dev is reasonably available.

Comment: It's usually not the case that you have actually “asked it [the code] to do anything”. The vast majority of real code out there doesn't have any formal specification at all whatsoever. Not even an informal one, written in a natural language. Most of what you want from the code has not even been articulated. It's more that the a buggy code does something that surprises you (or that the state or some data turns out to be surprising), and you feel displeased. So most of the bugs out there are purely subjectively defined.

Comment: Further, I don't think I wrote anywhere that a bug is a change. A bug can (but doesn't have to) manifest itself in a subjectively wrong change of the state of a program, but this needn't be the case. As for the term “incident”, it already contains an element of subjective surprise. Without specification and without humans, bugs simply don't exist. Probably you were confused by the term *deviation*. A deviation can be but needn't be a change.

Comment: @Flater As for your second comment, as a manager you sometimes don't have time or money to invest into teaching the developers. In certain cases, it's better to fire an bad one an to hire a better one. When saying „bad“, I silently implied that a developer is also unable or unwilling to learn by himself/herself.

Comment: The manager attitude on display in the last comment is **the** main contributor to bad dev cultures that I have observed in my 10 years as a consultant who was brought in to fix projects that were in trouble. Developer turnover is already a managerial difficulty of life. Leaning into it by increasing the turnover (barring the exceptional circumstance, but you phrased your comment much broader than that) is the opposite of good management. "Meat on the pile" management inherently does not value long term business knowledge, nor does it focus on mentoring employees on their personal trajectory

Comment: I want to take a moment to point out very clearly that your comment talks about firing and replacing someone when they don't/can't learn _by themselves_. It further suggests that the concept of mentoring is just not present in this work environment. This is starting to explain why your advice originates based on a binary bad/good label and not one of nuance and growth.

Comment: @Flater I also think that it's often better for everyone when you as a manager are also a mentor to your employees or at least when an employee has a mentor (who need not be the manager). At the same time, I saw my last mentor over 11 years ago, and certain folks I know are already in their fifties have never ever seen a mentor in their lives. So in practical terms, mentoring seems often infeasible, and you as a manager say *no* to 95% of the requests. I hate to say this, but personal/technical growth (which is want we want) often simply fall behind the main, countable, measurable objectives.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this question is really about the amount (if any) of help that you as a junior developer get from the testers on **how** to correct bugs identified by them. I trust that you appreciate that the essential sense of why bugs found by reviews of X's code (or indeed in the code allocated to X for maintenance) should be fixed by X: how else may X learn to write less buggy code ?

I say this as the phrasing of your question suggests an allocation of bugs to developers but no mention of how to write the bugged code better is passed on to the coder in your company. Just sending problems back to its coder without good feedback is useless.

A facet of many of the more recently established software companies is that junior developers are given little or no guidance. For the most part they are left to get to grips with the software system, the company's stated and unstated preferences in coding, the customer's needs and everything else all on their own. Some companies almost seem to intentionally create a Darwinian situation where it's every coder for him/herself and no help or mentoring is offered to new employees.

Maybe this is sometimes for saving money on software tester time/salaries - which cost much more than developer time/salaries. But maybe there is also a sort of predisposition among those ex-senior developers running such companies that disdains the human communication side of mentoring and training junior staff. Or disdains the concurrent need to listen to other perspectives from the junior staff - some perhaps a lot more potent than those applied in the company's existing code base.

But at any rate this no-guidance/DIY management is a fact of life within many software companies today and, despite the notable success that some tech companies implementing a better expertise <-> action/observation exchange process, this trend seems to be unchanging.

If I were you I would seek out a dev job in a company with a more positive approach to low-key mentoring of junior staff, even if this means working on a software product that is less "exciting" than others. That way you will learn your software engineering craft better. And, with the good example of senior devs/testers around you, you would also become a more inspiring developer yourself.